# How to pass an integer?

Tags: android, android-intent, menu, integer, boolean

How do I pass an integer to a public void method so I can pass the string to my other activity? I want the int number to be passed to the public void openActivityOne() method, but I can't get it right

```
public void openActivityOne(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);
    String strName = "4";
    intent.putExtra("magazine", strName);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.item1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Galerij geselecteerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.magazine:
            Toast.makeText(this, "item 2 geselecteerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.magazine1:
            int nummer = 1;
            openActivityOne();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an integer argument at `openActivityOne()`:

```
   public void openActivityOne(int n){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);
    // do what you want with n like
    intent.putExtra("something", n);
    String strName = "4";
    intent.putExtra("magazine", strName);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

and call:

```
case R.id.magazine1:
    int nummer = 1;
    openActivityOne(nummer);
    return true;
```

Comment: OMG thanks a lot. Idk why this took me so long to figure out lol